# Canvas ToDataUrl to simple image

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

Is there any way I can transform the data that I receive via toDataURL() into a simple image ending in .jpg or .png without having to download it?

My problem is that the data I receive with toDataURL, despite visualising perfectly into html tags, doesn't work with a ThreeJS script I'm working on.

[Here](http://creativiii.com/3Dproject/image.html) you can find of the generated image into an img src tag (there was too much text to link it here). If there was a way to just make all that text into a simple filename.png I'm sure it would fix most of my problems.

The image is currently being loaded to the OBJ using

```
child.material.map = new THREE.Texture(img);
```

Where "img" has been data straight from the canvas or the dataurl generated picture.

```
var img = c.toDataURL({
    format: 'png',
    width: 1024,
    height: 1024
})
```

I also tried using "c" and "ctx", but neither worked.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: Is it better now? I'd link the full script but it's a huge mess and doesn't work on Firefox for now. This was the suggested method of loading from canvas that I found after researching.

Comment: You should be able to create a texture from any `<img>` element. Show what `img` is in the line of code. Are you creating an `img` tag? Or is it only the data url string?

Comment: Updated. It's just the string.

Comment: Updated with what I just tried, neither "c" nor "ctx" worked.

Comment: Try this: `var image = document.createElement( 'img' );
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,XXXXX';
var texture = new THREE.Texture( image );
texture.needsUpdate = true;` (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3430#issuecomment-17426660)

Comment: gives me `(index):359 GET data:image/png;base64,XXXXX net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

Comment: You'll have to replace the `XXXXXX` by your own dataUrl. The example was meant to show you that you can make a texture from a data url string by creating a virtual `img` element and setting it as the `src` attribute.

Comment: Yeah I'm stupid, I figured that out after I posted haha. I just tried it, It's giving me a 404 `GET http://creativiii.com/3Dproject/undefined 404 (Not Found)`